# After Effects CC and Premiere CC Live Text after CC 2018

Tags: after-effects, premiere, adobe

I'm still using the 2018 version of Premiere and AE, I do know that they introduced the mogrt and other features to fast place block of graphics developed in ae and to be changed in premiere.

Now the 2018 version had the ability to change the texts in realtime via directlink.

I'm talking about this function:

Has this option been deprecated?

What if I'm working in premiere with various instances of graphics and suddenly I want to change the graphics in ae and go back in premiere ?

Given that the mogrt have to be saved outside ae and imported back in premiere, the ability to edit the file in ae and have premiere automatically updated is still here?

Or... do you have to finish completely the graphics in ae, export as file and work in premiere hoping that you will never need to change something in the ae graphic?

Thanks